# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los archivos con una determinada extensión dentro de un directorio?

Tags: linux, unix, búsquedas

Necesito obtener una lista de todos los archivos que están contenidos en el directorio /etc y que terminan por .conf. Además, la lista tiene que aparecer en orden alfabético y contener el nombre del directorio /etc.

Un ejemplo de lo que estoy buscando sería esto:
`/etc/adduser.conf`

Por el momento, he probado con `ls /etc | grep .conf$ | sort` y he obtenido algo como `adduser.conf`, pero sin el directorio `etc/`incluido en el nombre.

Me preguntaba si había alguna manera de conseguir lo que busco...

Comment: ¿Quieres también aquellos ficheros que están en subdirectorios? Por ejemplo un fichero como `/etc/network-scripts/bla.conf`, ¿lo quieres en la lista?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes aplicar el parámetro `-d1` en el `ls`, de manera que te muestre toda la ruta de los archivos.

Tu comando quedaría:

```
ls -d1 /etc/*.conf | sort
```

Comment: He probado a hacer esto pero no obtengo ningún resultado... no es que me dé error ni nada, simplemente no ocurre nada y me indica que puedo insertar un nuevo comando

Comment: perdona, me olvide de poner  1 en el parametro. Realmente es -d1. Lo he corregido en la solucion

Answer (score 1):

Usando GNU `find`:

```
find /etc -maxdepth 1 -name '*.conf' | sort
```

Explicación:

- `/etc`: El directorio desde el cuál serán buscados los archivos.
- `-maxdepth 1`: Desciende el nivel indicado de directorios. En este caso, listará los archivos dentro del directorio `/etc` pero no dentro de `/etc/dir`. Puedes eliminar esta opción si lo deseas.
- `-name '*.conf'`: Busca los archivos que coincidan con el patrón `*.conf` usando la sintaxis conocida como [*Pattern Matching*](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Shell-Pattern-Matching.html).

Puedes leer la documentación oficial usando el comando `man find` o en línea en el [sitio web oficial](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/find.html).

Por desgracia, la opción `-maxdepth` no es reconocida por POSIX pero puedes encontrar GNU `find` en prácticamente cualquier distribución GNU/Linux, macOS (Homebrew) y Windows (Cygwin, WSL).

En esta otra pregunta dan comandos compatibles con POSIX: [Limit POSIX find to specific depth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637)

Comment: He probado con el código que me dices pero no obtengo nada... También he probado eliminando `maxdepth 1` (tengo un Mac) y sigo sin conseguir ningún resultado

Comment: @aprendiz Intenta con `find /etc -name '*.conf' -print`

Comment: Dado que busca ficheros, puedes añadir `-type f`